# Getting Problem with SSL certificate for url when recording android emulator application with JMeter

Tags: java, android, ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate

I am facing a problem while recording the Android emulator Application with JMeter.
I am receiving:

```
2021-11-18 10:26:57,950 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
2021-11-18 10:26:57,950 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
2021-11-18 10:26:57,952 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8888
2021-11-18 10:26:57,952 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2021-11-18 10:26:58,219 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: In SSL request, unable to find host and port in CONNECT request: [2a00:1450:x:x::x]:443
2021-11-18 10:26:58,219 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: In SSL request, unable to find host and port in CONNECT request: [2a00:1450:x:x::x]:443
2021-11-18 10:26:58,247 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: [54290]  Creating entry 172.217.x.xxx in C:\Users\customuser\Desktop\Dev\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
2021-11-18 10:27:02,003 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54297]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:06,509 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54290]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host '172.217.x.xxx' in map with key (172.217.x.xxx)
2021-11-18 10:27:06,524 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54290]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '172.217.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:06,528 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54291]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '172.217.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:06,555 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54301]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:06,562 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54299]  Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for customuser to authorize the certificate for 172.217.x.xxx:443
2021-11-18 10:27:11,924 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54304]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '172.217.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:14,649 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54306]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:27:36,681 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54312]  Empty response to http over SSL. Probably waiting for customuser to authorize the certificate for 216.58.208.202:443
2021-11-18 10:27:44,673 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54315]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:28:06,237 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54321]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:28:14,652 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [54324]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:28:44,664 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [62495]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:29:14,655 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [62502]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:29:44,665 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64461]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:30:06,284 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: [64468]  Creating entry 216.58.x.xxx in C:\Users\customuser\Desktop\Dev\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
2021-11-18 10:30:14,766 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64468]  KeyStore for SSL loaded OK and put host '216.58.x.xxx' in map with key (216.58.x.xxx)
2021-11-18 10:30:14,779 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64468]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '216.58.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:30:14,784 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64476]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:30:44,673 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64484]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:31:14,648 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64494]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:31:44,694 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64505]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:14,653 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64519]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:14,839 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [64520]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '216.58.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:28,425 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65004]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:28,466 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: In SSL request, unable to find host and port in CONNECT request: [2a00:1450:x:x::x]:443
2021-11-18 10:32:28,486 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65006]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:28,517 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65008]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:28,542 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65009]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:32:44,668 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65027]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:33:14,654 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65042]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:33:44,661 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65050]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:34:14,647 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65060]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:34:14,894 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65061]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '216.58.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:34:44,683 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65070]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:35:14,646 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65079]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:35:44,666 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65086]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '91.206.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:36:14,953 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [65097]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for '142.250.x.xxx'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021-11-18 10:38:07,042 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
```

My android application uses an SSL mechanism and the configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system" />
            <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">m.domain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>

    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">domain.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <another pins for certificates...>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">cLaZXMWnbSRFEtZahBG19ZoDhmWQxHuz8zfRWlko7zs=</pin>
        </pin-set>
        <trustkit-config enforcePinning="false" />
    </domain-config>

    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">a.domain.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <another pins for certificates...>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">cLaZXMWnbSRFEtZahBG19ZoDhmWQxHuz8zfRWlko7zs=</pin>
        </pin-set>
        <trustkit-config enforcePinning="false" />
    </domain-config>

    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">main.domain.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <another pins for certificates...>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">cLaZXMWnbSRFEtZahBG19ZoDhmWQxHuz8zfRWlko7zs=</pin>
        </pin-set>
        <trustkit-config enforcePinning="false" />
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I obtained a public pin for my `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` with the command:

```
openssl x509 -in ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

[image: cert]

[image: emulator]

[image]

Moreover, a certificate has been installed on my Pixel emulator and it's visible. Additionally, I enabled proxy on my emulator but it didn't bring a desirable effect.
I checked different proxies IPs, ports, emulator versions, installing cert for wifi and VPN on the emulator and I still face the problem. Will be grateful for suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to amend [Android network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in order to trust JMeter's self-signed certificate

1. In the [application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) section of your app [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) add the following entry:

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config
   ```
2. Add `network_security_config.xml` file to your application [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and put the following code there:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
          <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
          <certificates src="user" />
       </trust-anchors>
      </debug-overrides>
    </network-security-config>
   ```
3. [Re-compile your application in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode):

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
4. Replace the app you're trying to record with the debug .apk from the previous step
5. You should be able to record now

More information: [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording)